# Не запускается mvn package

Tags: java, spring-mvc, maven

Всплывает такая ошибка:
`[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\Users\User). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory.`
Я понимаю что надо поменять каталог откуда вызывается POM, но как именно это сделать не знаю. Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно вызывать `mvn package` в папке с вашим проектом.
В консоле необходимо перейти командой `cd <path to your project>`.

К примеру

```
cd "C:\Users\User\MyProject"
mvn package
```